# New Chart.js Chart onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to get the most out of Chart.js' [beautiful animations](http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/line/basic.html) in a new web project. I'm using a tabbed structure for most of the content. My chart is on tab Three of Four.

Right now the chart is drawing/building on load. How do I make it so when #chartTrigger (Tab Three) is clicked, a new chart is drawn?

And is it possible to limit the number of animations? If a user clicks Tab Three then ventures off to Tab Four for a bit then decides to return to Tab Three, can we stop the animation from displaying again?

Here is a live demo of what I've got: https://codepen.io/drewalth/pen/wppNbJ

```
<style>
body {
  font-family:sans-serif;
}

div.tab button {
   border: none;
   outline: none;
   cursor: pointer;
   padding: 0.6em 1em;
   flex-basis: 12%;
   color: #34495E;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
   text-transform: capitalize;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    background-color: #BDC3C7;
}
div.tab button.active {
    background-color: #34495E;
    color:#fff;
}

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  height:300px;
  width:50%;
  color:#fff;
  padding:35px;
}

#tabOne {
  background-color:#E74C3C;
}
#tabTwo {
  background-color:#3498DB;
}

#tabThree {
  text-align:center;
}

#tabFour {
  background-color:#2ECC71;
}


</style>

<div class="tab">
            <button id="defaultOpen" class="tablinks" 
onclick="openTab(event, 'tabOne')">Tab One</button>
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 
'tabTwo')">Tab Two</button>
            <button id="chartTrigger" class="tablinks" 
onclick="openTab(event, 'tabThree')">Tab Three</button>
            <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 
'tabFour')">Tab Four</button>

        </div>
<div id="tabOne" class="tabcontent">
  Click Tab Three for Chart
</div>
<div id="tabTwo" class="tabcontent">

</div>
<div id="tabThree" class="tabcontent">
  <canvas id="test-chart" height="500"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="tabFour" class="tabcontent">

</div>
<script>

// function to switch between tabs

function openTab(evt, tabName) {

  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", 
"");
  }

  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
 }

document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();

// Working Chart.js

var ctx = document.getElementById("test-chart").getContext('2d');
    var newTestChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: ["10/21", "10/22", "10/23", "10/24", "10/25", "10/26", 
"10/27", "10/28", "10/29", "10/30", "10/31", "11/01", "11/02", "11/03", 
"11/04"],
        datasets: [{
          data: [150, 550, 500, 880, 200, 100, 102, 102, 99, 105, 100, 
 103, 100, 102, 100],
          backgroundColor: ['rgba(77, 112, 144, 0.4)', ],
          borderColor: ['rgba(77, 112, 144,1)', ],
          borderWidth: 2
        }]
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        defaultFontFamily: "'Titillium Web'",
        defaultFontSize: 16,
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true
            }
          }]
        },
      }
    });



// What I'd like to see happen...

var $chartTrigger = document.getElementById("chartTrigger");

$chartTrigger.onclick(newChart);

</script>
```

Comment: Do mark the answer as correct if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should move the chart code inside the `openTab` and use a global variable as a flag to see if the chart is loaded once then dont load it again see the [codepen](https://codepen.io/buttflattery/pen/gooEqo) or demo  below

```js
// function to switch between tabs
var isLoaded = false;

function openTab(evt, tabName) {

  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";

  if (tabName == 'tabThree' && !isLoaded) {
    isLoaded = true;
    // Working Chart.js
    console.log('loaded');
    var ctx = document.getElementById("test-chart").getContext('2d');
    var newTestChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: ["10/21", "10/22", "10/23", "10/24", "10/25", "10/26", "10/27", "10/28", "10/29", "10/30", "10/31", "11/01", "11/02", "11/03", "11/04"],
        datasets: [{
          data: [150, 550, 500, 880, 200, 100, 102, 102, 99, 105, 100, 103, 100, 102, 100],
          backgroundColor: ['rgba(77, 112, 144, 0.4)', ],
          borderColor: ['rgba(77, 112, 144,1)', ],
          borderWidth: 2
        }]
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        defaultFontFamily: "'Titillium Web'",
        defaultFontSize: 16,
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true
            }
          }]
        },
      }
    });


  }
}

document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

div.tab button {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  padding: 0.6em 1em;
  flex-basis: 12%;
  color: #34495E;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  background-color: #BDC3C7;
}

div.tab button.active {
  background-color: #34495E;
  color: #fff;
}

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  height: 300px;
  width: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 35px;
}

#tabOne {
  background-color: #E74C3C;
}

#tabTwo {
  background-color: #3498DB;
}

#tabThree {
  text-align: center;
}

#tabFour {
  background-color: #2ECC71;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab">
  <button id="defaultOpen" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'tabOne')">Tab One</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'tabTwo')">Tab Two</button>
  <button id="chartTrigger" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'tabThree')">Tab Three</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'tabFour')">Tab Four</button>

</div>
<div id="tabOne" class="tabcontent">
  Click Tab Three for Chart
</div>
<div id="tabTwo" class="tabcontent">

</div>
<div id="tabThree" class="tabcontent">
  <canvas id="test-chart" height="500"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="tabFour" class="tabcontent">

</div>
```